# Iptv carregar lista - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de saber, tenho que carregar uma lista IPTV:
Algumas dessas listas são em .xml, mas esta em questão não é. Como faço para importar

Mas eu não consigo saber o que segue cada lista dessa:

```
#EXTINF: -1, Martanela TV
http://auth.nnm-list.ru/h/921d/1/1/niu3uo4w

#EXTINF: -1, Calarai
http://auth.nnm-list.ru/h/918/1/1/niu3uo4w

#EXTINF: -1, Clouder TV
http://auth.nnm-list.ru/h/540/1/1/niu3uo4w

#EXTINF:0,Bluta
rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://195.154.176.66:8082/ playpath=private swfUrl=http://livestreamcast.org/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://ero-tv.org/redlight_online/
```

O que tenho que seguir, pararetirar dados de uma lista do tipo, qual programa utiliza esta lista?

Comment: Esta é uma lista de canais IPTV, qual aspecto dela você não compreendeu? o que você precisa fazer?

Comment: Na realidade não sei se segue uma ordem,  existe uma lista de iptv que segue alguma ordem... eu criei a minha própria usando xml... mas gostaria de importar de outros programas... mas oque as deles seguem como ordem? Att...

Comment: O aplicativo "playlist loader" lê essa lista. [Esse link pode ajudá-lo](http://kodinow.com/pt/2015/07/how-to-create-your-own-custom-iptv-playlist/)